# VS Code can't recognize Java project or can't detect Java project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

When I open the Java project in VS Code, it can't recognize Java language and the Java build status is always "Building" and when I see the java log the build status doesn't show anything.

I have already installed Java extension pack.

It makes it hard for me to import Java libraries and also hard to get autocomplete when I code Java.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, by adding `-Xlog:jni+resolve=off` to `java.jdt.ls.vmargs` and it's solved

Answer (score 1):

First, you must install everything from the [*Extension Pack for Java*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) and the [*Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) extension.

Second, you have to make sure you open the correct project folder. Because VS Code takes the opened folder as the workspace, So pay attention to the folder hierarchy you open.